# How to integrate Django user system with Google Cloud Endpoint authentication?

Tags: django, google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints

I'm trying to expose an API for an existing Django app using App Engine python endpoints. The API is intended for javascript web client, and it should use the existing Django user system for authentication.

Django authentication is cookie based, while Google Cloud Endpoints is based on OAuth2. How is it possible to integrate the two?